# Why I can't show datas

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

When I run the code, the required information does not appear in the gridbox. [image]

```
{
    public partial class fatura : Form
    {
        SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=master; Trusted_Connection=True");
        DataTable tablo;
        araba_ekleme araba_ekleme = new araba_ekleme();
        public fatura()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public DataTable listele(SqlDataAdapter adtr, string sorgu)
        {
            tablo = new DataTable();
            adtr = new SqlDataAdapter(sorgu, baglanti);
            adtr.Fill(tablo);
            baglanti.Close();
            return tablo;
        }
        private void onay_bekleyen()
        {
            string cumle = "declare @tc_no bigint select tc_no,car_plate,total,date,tax from [invoice] WHERE (status=0) AND tc_no=@tc_no";
            SqlDataAdapter adtr2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
            dg_pending.DataSource = listele(adtr2, cumle);
        }
        private void onaylanan()
        {
            string cumle = "declare @tc_no bigint select tc_no,car_plate,total,date,tax from [invoice] WHERE (status=1) AND tc_no=@tc_no";
            SqlDataAdapter adtr2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
            dg_done.DataSource = listele(adtr2, cumle);
        }
        private void fatura_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            onay_bekleyen();
            onaylanan();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code it gives an error. `string cumle = "select tc_no,car_plate,total,date,tax from [invoice] WHERE (status=0) AND tc_no=@tc_no";`

So i used this code block `string cumle = "declare @tc_no bigint select tc_no,car_plate,total,date,tax from [invoice] WHERE (status=0) AND tc_no=@tc_no";` and when I run the code, the required information does not appear in the gridbox.

Comment: baglanti.Open() ?? i dont see

Comment: Don't tell us that you get an error message and then don't tell us what it is and exactly where it occurred. Sometimes we can work out our anyway but we shouldn't have to.

Comment: You are not adding the query parameters. See [Working with SqlClient Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapter-parameters#working-with-sqlclient-parameters). Also, the `SqlDataAdapter` parameter in `listele` makes no sense as it is unused.

Answer (score 0):

edit `(SqlDataAdapter adtr, string sorgu)` function like the code below:

1- You don't need to send `SqlDataAdapter as input` and define it inside the function.

2- You must open the connection.

3- `Use using` for `SqlDataAdapter and SqlConnection` so that there is no need to dispose.

4- Use `try- catch` to catch the error (In the following function, if there is an error, it will be displayed as a meesageBox. You can write error in file, console or anywhere else)

```
    public DataTable listele(string sorgu)
    {
        DataTable tablo = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection MyConnnection = new SqlConnection(conString ))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sorgu, MyConnnection))
            {
                try
                {
                    MyConnnection.Open();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(tablo);
                }catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        return tablo;
    }
```

define `connection string`:

```
public partial class fatura : Form
{
    public string conString = "Server=localhost;Database=master; Trusted_Connection=True";
    SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=master; Trusted_Connection=True");
    DataTable tablo;
    araba_ekleme araba_ekleme = new araba_ekleme();
    ...
```

Call the function as below:

```
 dg_pending.DataSource = listele(cumle);
```

Comment: There's no need to open the connection explicitly. The Fill and Update methods will open the connection implicitly if it's not already open and close it implicitly if it was opened. You would only open the connection explicitly if you wanted to use it for multiple Fill or Update calls without closing and reopening in between.

Comment: @jmcilhinney
 https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/61b832/sqldataadapter-fill-method/

Comment: Why do you think the fact that you found someone else recommending the same pointless action would interest me? Maybe you should read the relevant documentation.

Comment: Here, I got it for you: *"The connection object associated with the SELECT statement must be valid, but it does not need to be open. If the connection is closed before Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data, then closed. If the connection is open before Fill is called, it remains open."*

Comment: @jmcilhinney The difference is that if the connection string is wrong. It gives an error when opening the connection. I think it is not very important whether you open the connection or not

Comment: @hossein-sabziani I get the error "baglanti" is not null here

Comment: @Axciom i edit my answer. now check :)

Comment: @hossein-sabziani The code worked but the datagrid is still empty :(

Comment: @Axciom Put a breakpoint on the output of the function to see tablo has data or not

Comment: Firstly, the connection has to be opened either way, whether it be implicitly or explicitly, so your going to get the same exception either way. Secondly, if you don't think it matters either way, your answer probably shouldn't state that it MUST be done one particular way. You're implying that the OP was wrong not to do it that way but they weren't.